# Model not found in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

**Error** : FatalErrorException in PhotoController.php line 17: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\photo' not found

exception occur on this code -> $a = photo::all();

```
**PhotoController ** 

   <?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use App\Http\Requests;
    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    class PhotoController extends Controller { 
    public function index()
    {
        $a = photo::all();
        print_r($a); 
    }


    **// Photo  model** 

    <?php namespace App;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
    class Photo extends Model { 
        protected $table = 'users';  
    }
```

Comment: I don't know why I got the same error the second time I did it, but there is no need to change the namespaces of the controller and the model (in fact it will be much worse for your architecture). Just write `use App\Photo` in your `PhotoController`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace in Controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\models\Photo;
```

Replace in Model

```
namespace App\models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
```

Comment: No need to change the namespace of the model. `use App\Photo` is sufficient