# Laravel Model not being found

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller

Hi there I am having trouble using a model within a class there error being shown is Error
Class 'App\Models\RegisteredUsers' not found.

I have made sure that the namespaces match what is being used but I repeatedly get the same error.

Model code

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class RegisteredUsers extends Model
{
    //
}
```

Controller code

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\RegisteredUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;

class RegisterUser extends Controller
{
$UserObj = new RegisteredUsers();
}
```

The directory
App/Http/Controllers/RegisterUser - controller

App/Http/Models/RegisteredUser - model

I created the model and the controller using the command line with PHP artisan.
I have tried the solutions from
[laravel model class not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42752552/laravel-model-class-not-found)
as well as [Model not found in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28688872/model-not-found-in-laravel)
and a few laracast questions but i still get the error.

Comment: you put that model in the `app/Models` directory and the filename is `RegisteredUsers.php`?

Comment: Directories are mapped to namespaces, that's how the autoloader finds the classes it needs. It's not going to look at `App/Http/Models/RegisteredUser.php` if your class is `App/Models/RegisteredUser`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `App\Models` namespace in your `RegsiteredUser` model, the **RegisteredUser.php** model file must be in the **app/Models/RegisteredUser.php** directory. Try to **move the Models folder outside the Http folder**. And from now, you should never put the Models folder in the Http folder again.

Answer (score 2):

May need to rebuild the classmap

`composer dump-autoload`

Answer (score 0):

Your error is **App/Http/Models/RegisteredUser** and **use App\Models\RegisteredUsers;**, did you place your Models in Http?. that is not correct, the Models should be in App root directory, so you are calling the **RegisteredUser** in the wrong place